# Is there a more efficient way to find the missing integer?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm currently studying a module called data structures and algorithms at a university. We've been tasked with writing an algorithm that finds the smallest positive integer which does not occur in a given sequence. I was able to find a solution, but is there a more efficient way?

```
x = [5, 6, 3, 1, 2]

def missing_integer():
    for i in range(1, 100):
        if i not in x:
            return i

print(missing_integer())
```

The instructions include some examples:
given x = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5,
given x = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4 and
given x = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Comment: @OmG: Your linked question states that only one integer (in a given range) is missing from the array, while the question here allows many to be missing and asks for the smallest such to be returned. That is a very different matter, requiring a very different algorithm. This question also does not have a previously determined range. So this question is not a duplicate of that other one.

Comment: Are all values in `x` guaranteed to be unique (and positive)?

Comment: The only big problem that jumps out to me is the arbitrary search range, what if your list is above 100? Or starts above 1? Consider perhaps changing `range(1,100)` to `range(min(x), max(x)+1)`

Comment: Based on the instructions, I think the numbers in x can contain duplicates and negative numbers. It does give some examples: given x = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5, given x = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4 and given x = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Comment: If there's a small number of potential values you could use a bitmask.

Comment: @Jaye Note, though, that the presence of non-positive integers doesn't affect the answer, so you can simply pretend there are none. (As a first step, you can just remove all such values, and then concentrate on what is left.)

Comment: (Welcome to stackoverflow!) Please edit the examples from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655701/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-find-the-missing-integer#comment96103502_54655701) into the question.

Comment: This could be solved in `O(n log n)` using a heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slow step in your algorithm is that line:

```
if i not in x:
```

That step takes linear time, which makes the entire algorithm `O(N*N)`. If you first turn the list into a set, the lookup is much faster:

```
def missing_integer():
    sx = set(x)
    for i in range(1, 100):
        if i not in sx:
            return i
```

Lookup in a set is fast, in fact it takes constant time, and the algorithm now runs in linear time O(N).

Comment: Also, why go up to 100 when it's enough to go up to 6?

Comment: It was an assumption in the instructions. I've changed it to the length of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You did not ask for the most efficient way to solve the problem, just if there is a more efficient way than yours. The answer to that is **yes**.

If the missing integer is near the top of the range of the integers and the list is long, your algorithm as a run-time efficiency of `O(N**2)`--your loop goes through all possible values, and the `not in` operator searches through the entire list if a match is not found. (Your code searches only up to the value `100`--I assume that is just a mistake on your part and you want to handle sequences of any length.)

Here is a simple algorithm that is merely order `O(N*log(N))`. (Note that quicker algorithms exist--I show this one since it is simple and thus answers your question easily.) Sort the sequence (which has the order I stated) then run through it starting at the smallest value. This linear search will easily find the missing positive integer. This algorithm also has the advantage that  the sequence could involve negative numbers, non-integer numbers, and repeated numbers, and the code could easily handle those. This also handles sequences of any size and with numbers of any size, though of course it runs longer for longer sequences. If a good sort routine is used, the memory usage is quite small.

Comment: For completeness, note that there *is* an O(n) algorithm; sorting is not the most efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, I meant to mention that but left it out. I'll add that now. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `O(n)` algorithm goes like this: initialise an array record of length `n + 2` (list in Python) to `None`, and iterate over the input. If the element is one of the array indexes, set the element in the record to `True`. Now iterate over the new list record starting from index 1. Return the first `None` encountered.

Comment: Nice use of a sentinel. (No need to check for the end of the array during the "early out" search for an unmodified element as there is known to be at least one.

Comment: @greybeard the question states, "smallest positive integer which does not occur in a given sequence." How do you assume there is known to be a missing element?

Comment: `How [does greybeard] assume there is known to be a missing element` by virtue of `[array] of length n + 1` with n entries made.

Comment: @greybeard the record is length `n + 1` since the first (entry 0 -> index 0) is unattended. Its length is `n` for  practical purposes.

Comment: @greybeard I think I finally got what you were saying :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is creating an array with a size of `Max` value, and traverse the array and marking each location of the array when that value is seen. Then, iterate from the start of the array and report the first finding unlabeled location as the smallest missing value. This is done in `O(n)` (Fill the array and finding the smallest unlabeled location).

Also, for negative values you can add all values the `Min` value to find all values positive. Then, apply the above method. 
The space complexity of this method is `\Theta(n)`.

To know more, see [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-positive-number-missing-from-an-unsorted-array/) about the implementation and scrutinize more about this method.

Comment: "[create] an array with a size of `Max` value" - this does not seem practical if some of the entries are large (e.g., in the billions).

Comment: (`[size of Max value] does not seem practical` well, if max greater 0, take the min of max and length.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן yes. it's a complementary solution when it is practical (for small size n). Indeed for a proper size `n` it is more practical than sorting! : )

Answer (score -1):

Can be done in O(n) time with a bit of maths. initialise a minimum_value and maximum_value, and sum_value names then loop once through the numbers to find the minimum and maximum and the sum of all the numbers `(mn, mx, sm)`.

Now the sum of integers `0..n = n*(n-1)/2 = s(n)`

Therefore: `missing_number = (s(mx) - s(mn)) - sm`

All done with traversing the numbers only once!

Comment: This algorithm only works if there is just *one* number missing, but that may not be the case. It also does not work if the minimum is `2` since the returned value should be `1`.

Comment: There IS only one missing integer mentioned at time of writing. Nothing special about 2 that I can see, please explain.

Comment: The problem statement does *not* include the count of `integer`s missing or a promise of uniqueness. The example shows exactly one missing. More examples were added in a comment, including on with no "element missing from the middle", one with a duplicate, and one where the expected result is way above `maximum_value`.

Answer (score -1):

My answer using list comprehension:

```
def solution(A):
    max_val = max(A);
    min_val = min(A);
    if max_val<0: val = 1;    
    elif max_val > 0:
        li = [];
        [li.append(X) for X in range(min_val,max_val) if X not in A];
        if len(li)>0: 
            if min(li)<0: val = 1;
            else: val = min(li);
        if len(li)==0: val=max_val+1;
    return val;
L = [-1, -3];
res = solution(L);
print(res);
```